# Why does finonachi(8) + fibonachi(7) = 34 and not 15?

Tags: python, fibonacci

My goal was to make some code representing a Fibonacci spiral. In my adventures, I found some code to make one. I wanted to study it to see what it would do. However, I seem to have gotten the wrong outputs.

```
def fibonachi(n):
    if n < 0:
        print("Incorrect number")


    elif n == 1 or n == 2:
       return 1
    else:
       return fibonachi(n - 1) + fibonachi(n - 2)
print(fibonachi(9))
```

Expected output: 15 (cause 8 + 7 = 15)
Actual output: 34

This lines up with what is supposed to happen, but I dont understand how this happens. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Because fibonacci(8) is not 8 and fibonacci(7) is not 7.  You can confirm by calculating fibonacci sequence from n = 3.  You know fibonacci(1)=fibonacci(2)=1 as you code.  Then fibonachi(3) = fibonacci(1)+fibonacci(2)=2. You can calculate the sequence in this way.

Comment: Nope, your code is correct, your calculation of fib is wrong  https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the name of the mathematician is `Fibonacci`, not `fibonachi` or `finonachi`.

Comment: The Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following integer sequence.
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144,

Comment: @bdbd: What? That's not how the computation works at all.

Comment: hope we are talking about Fibonacci

Comment: Yes I was wrong. Deleted lol

Comment: and you're not gonna able to draw any real usable spirals because your code is extremely inefficient and will take a significant time just to calculate a small number of points

Answer (score 1):

You did not implement the case where `n == 0`:

```
def fibonacci(n):
if n < 0:
    print("Incorrect number")
elif n == 0:
    return 0


elif n == 1 or n == 2:
   return 1
else:
   return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
print(fibonacci(9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I got it.

Basically, when I called fibo 9, the code i wrote told it to call for fibo 8 and fibo 7. Those two seperate into their own fibos, until N == 1 or 2. Then, the code adds it all together into a nice 34.